# Multiple Laravel instances in the same dashboard

Tags: git, laravel, dashboard, microservices

I want to build a dashboard where e.g. every navigation item leads to its own laravel instance. There are a couple of reasons why I want it this way:

- It's an intranet application with many microservices
- In this case it's important to not just seperate API from Views but also to seperate the applications from each other as well

One approach I could think of is that I could make a repository with

- The dashboard itself (master templates, js files, css files etc.)
- A model that fetches the navigation from a database

This dashboard repo could be a dependency for building the others on it but I'm not quite sure if this is even easily shareable accross the instances without a massive ovearhead

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm I actually got an idea: building a core-application repo and then fork from this one; this way I can share updates in core to all instances - this might work... kinda feels like an akward fundamental question of software development approaches :)

Comment: how about you use REST api to manage all of that?

Comment: I do use a REST api for that but as mentioned I need to seperate the applications in the dashboard as well (all controllers, even the composer  dependencies) It's an intranet dashboard with lots of applications and I dont wan't to update them all at once when I need to. Also I want to be able to just shut one down without picking single files from a single laravel instance (controller, views, css, js, etc.)